# How do I create a bundle of reusable code in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, bundle

I am developing an iPhone app and have to parse xml files in order to put them into a database. I will also be using those same xml parsers in my app so users can import their own data. I was wondering how I can extract those xml parsers into a bundle or a library so I can use them both in my iPhone app and in a command line app where I just populate a sqlite3 database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

Create a static library project, then use the interproject dependency feature of Xcode to build them in the correct order and link the app with the static library. You'll need to have a common build directory set for all the projects for this to work correctly (at least you did around Xcode 3.0, didn't check if this is still a problem with 3.1).

You can set the build directory from the target or project's build settings (in the Get Info pane). To create an interpoject dependency:

- Drag the library project into the application project's Files & Groups pane.
- Set up target dependency in the application target's Get Info pane. Make it dependent on the library's target.
- Drag the library product in the application target's Link With Libraries step. You can find the library product by expanding the library project within the app project's Files & Groups (click the arrow).

Sounds more complicated than it is. It isn't much.

(Small extras: yes, you need a common build folder as indicated in the [Xcode Project Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/070-Building_Products/chapter_8_section_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002693-SW10), and the [Xcode Build System Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/index.html) can help you "get" Xcode's build system, which -- at the cost of starting a religion war -- I think is one of the most flexible and simple build systems out there.)

Comment: thanks for your detailed response.  I will try it out when I get home tonight

Comment: You don't need to use a common build directory as of Xcode 3.1.1 (not 3.1).