# What is the recommended way to reuse utility functions among apps in my Xcode based iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, shared-libraries

I have some utility functions like:

```
void myVibratePhone() 
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) ;
}
```

that I'd like to use across all my projects.

In C, I'd give each project the header file, and link in the .OBJ file (or perhaps create a library).

What is the Apple-approved recommended way to share code (cocoa and C primarily) among my apps? Would I need a framework for this? How would I go about creating one?

Also, since I'm using subversion for version control, if I use a framework, do I place the version of the framework that the app is using in the subversion repository for the project  so that anyone who checks it out can build it straight away or make it a requirement that people check out a project + check out the utility functions also for a successful build of any project?

I don't plan on putting anything on the App Store at this time, but I don't want to do anything that will cause apple to not accept an app in any case.

I found this writeup about xcode 3.0 (I'm using Xcode 3.2.1):

[How do I create a bundle of reusable code in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-create-a-bundle-of-reusable-code-in-xcode)

I followed it, but am having one issue:

1) trouble finding my library .h file in the main project: I've tried both hardcoding it in the main projects .h file

```
#import "file://localhost/Users/piesia/Documents/My Utilities/MyUtilities.h"
```

as well as:

```
#import "/Users/piesia/Documents/My Utilities/MyUtilities.h"
```

and

```
    #import "~/Documents/My Utilities/MyUtilities.h"
```

I've also tried updating Header search paths in the Project Build settings:

```
"/Users/piesia/Documents/My Utilities/**"
```

when using #import

After a lot of trying (and replacing %20 with space), I was only able to get the variants

```
#import "/Users/piesia/Documents/My Utilities/MyUtilities.h"
```

and

```
#import "../../My Utilities/MyUtilities.h"
```

but I'd prefer not to hard code the path if I can figure out a better way.

So, in closing, 1) is the writeup that I'm following the recommended way to do shared code in Xcode 2) is it recommended that I keep the shared files in a separate subversion repository from the main program and link and include it in as I'm doing now and 3) do you know what I'm doing wrong in my attempts at loading the shared header file? Would anything that I'm doing or not doing with shared code hurt my chances of getting approval if I ever decided to submit it to the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with creating a static library to share the code.

To add the headers to the project you need to set the "User Header Search Paths" to the location of the `.h` files.

You then import the headers using something similar to:

`#import "YourHeader.h"`

You shouldn't need any additional path information in the import if the header search path is set correctly.

Comment: Yes, once I use "User Header Search Paths" (instead of Header Search Paths) #import "My Utilities.h" works! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh this one is a bugger! - I think unfortunately the easiest way is to hardcode.

Comment: To anyone else who has trouble with adding your utility project to you r main project:

1) drag your Xcode project (with an A on the icon)from the utility project Groups and Files to the top level of Groups and Files in your main project

2) in the Application target in the Targets section of your main project, Get Info of the application target (has a stylized A with a pencil), in the General section, click on + to create a Direct Dependency for your Utility project.

Comment: 3) click on the triangle by your Utility Xcode project in the main project Groups and Files, drag the utility library.a file that is in your utility project down to the Link Binary With Libraries section of your main application (hit the arrow next to it to open it up) in Targets.

In the .H file of your source that needs to use a utility function, put #import "My utility.h" (with your utility header's name). Make sure that you update your Project's "User Header Search Paths" to include the path to your utility path (fully qualified).

Thanks Eric and Ben S!

Comment: Oh, and BTW, if your User Header Search Path has a space in it, it must be delimited with " and ", e.g., "/Here is a path/with/spaces/" because spaces delimit separate elements of the User Header Search Path.

Best regards, Piesia

Answer (score 1):

My team has dozens of reusable components in our products, many of them shared between Mac and iPhone. My experience in this is that most of the time it's much easier to just include the source code rather than to create a separate static library. The separate project for the library adds a lot of complexity and seldom provides much value. Here is how I usually approach it:

In subversion we have a directory tree like this:

```
/common
    /Component1
    /Component2
/Project1
/Project2
...
```

In Project1.xcodeproj, we just drag in "Existing files" from common into the tree (don't copy). Doing it this way avoids lots of overhead in managing another project. This does mean that changes to the common tree can break any of the projects. That means you need to recompile everything before committing (we use a top-level build script to check that you didn't break anything). The advantage of the static library is that you can stage this by upgrading the library for each project when it's ready. On the other hand, it means that you have to rev the library often and manage syncing it around. We've found that just sharing the code directly typically is much more effective.

Comment: Thanks, Rob! That's a way I hadn't considered that looks also very useful.