# Exposing XCODE project as library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

How can I release a library for my XCODE project? I have a project which I wanted to expose to others as a library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a bundle of reusable code in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-create-a-bundle-of-reusable-code-in-xcode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must make a **Cocoa Touch Static Library** That contains all of the header and implementation files that you want to ship, and then use a script similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#build the device
echo building for ARM architecture
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos4.2 "ARCHS=armv6 armv7" build > /dev/null
#build the simulator
echo building for the i386 architecture
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator4.2 "ARCHS=i386 x86_64" "VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64" build > /dev/null
#make the folder
mkdir "Fat Binary"
#lipo suck it together
echo lipo binaries together
lipo -output Fat\ Binary/libMyLib.a -create build/Release-iphoneos/libmyLib.a build/Release-iphonesimulator/libmyLib.a
echo lipo binary saved at $./Fat Binary/libmyLib.a
echo coping headers
cp -R build/Release-iphoneos/usr "Fat Binary"
echo [COMPLETE]
```

This, in a nutshell, creates a folder that contains a library (libmyLib.a) and a folder of headers (usr) that must be added into the target project, the headers by Add->Existing Files and the Library by Add->Existing Framework->Add Other.

Also note that the role of the headers in your library must be public, or they will not copy, and that you must replace instances of `libmyLib.a` with the name of your library.

I have used this process many times, and it is the best you can get to making a framework for the iOS at this time, sadly.

Comment: From where do I need to run this script? How will this copy my project files in it. I have created the static library and put all the header, classes and libraries in appropriate folder inside it

Comment: Execute it from the same folder as the `.xcodeproj`. E.G. If your project is stored at `~/Documents/MyStaticLibrary/MyStaticLibrary.xcodeproj`, then you execute that from `~/Documents/MyStaticLibrary/`